# MediaPlayer doesn't play in background when started by an intent

Tags: android, android-intent, media-player

In my app I download an mp3 podcast and then play it with MediaPlayer using an intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

Uri data = Uri.parse("file://" + filepath);
intent.setDataAndType(data, "audio/*");

try {
        startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

}
```

This works, but unfortunately the player pauses as soon as I leave it, ie. when it goes to the background. When opened manually the player happily plays in the background.

**What do I need to make it play in background when starting it with an intent?**

*Just to clarify, I don't want to start the player in the background, I just wonder why it stops when it looses focus.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do I need to make it play in background when starting it with an intent?

You don't do it that way. You use the `MediaPlayer` class and operate it from within a service.

Comment: I know that, but I intentionally want to launch the external player for various reasons. Just like when you use an intent to launch the webbrowser instead of showing the content in a webview.

Comment: @marlar: Then you should neither know nor care whether the media is playing in the background or not. That is up to the other application, not you -- and bear in mind that there are dozens upon dozens of applications that the user might choose given your `Intent`, each of which will have its own characteristics. If you want control, implement media playback yourself.

Comment: You are right. I just updated my phone to gingerbread and now MediaPlayer behaves differently. Before it opened normally (except it didn't play when in background) but now it is a small transparent window on top of my own app. Conclusively, there is no way to guarantee a certain behaviour of MediaPlayer or whatever receives the intent, given the large number of phones, Android versions and app that might be installed.

Comment: Please see CommonsWare's answer here with links to a couple of very helpful examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305407/how-to-design-activity-service-interaction-for-a-simple-mp3-player